# Is it possible to check how close we are to our API call limit before making a call through the API?

Tags: api, soap-api, limits

We use Salesforce to manage our website logins & access to our products. If something goes wrong with our site or it gets attacked, we quickly go over our API call limit which means that our store & site go down. Is it possible to check where we are in terms of our API call limit so we can stop calling Salesforce before there's a problem (we're calling the SOAP API)? I've been looking through the developer docs & haven't been able to find anything that might help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a header returned for both the [SOAP API](http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_header_limitinfo.htm) and [REST API](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/headers_api_usage.htm). See the documentation for details.

Responses appear as:

## REST (header)

```
Sforce-Limit-Info: api-usage=18/5000
```

## SOAP (SOAP header in XML payload)

```
<soapenv:Header>
    <LimitInfoHeader>
        <limitInfo>
            <current>5</current>
            <limit>5000</limit>
            <type>API REQUESTS</type>
        </limitInfo>
    </LimitInfoHeader>
</soapenv:Header>
```

Comment: its in the soap api as well (in fact was in the soap api before the rest api). limit info is returned as a response soap header.

Comment: @superfell Thanks for that. I'd never seen in the documentation previously; every time I looked for it, I couldn't find it. I've found the related documentation and updated this answer.